# How do I filter a RESTful collection resource? Query parameters or query strings?

Tags: api, rest

I need to filter a list of employees and support both simple and complex queries.
RESTful APIs have query paramaters which are key value pairs provided after the ?

```
/employees?location=london
```

What would be used if I wanted to reduce the list to Employees with a start date between 01/01/2020 and 01/05/2020 that are also male and work at the Birmingham office?
Is this where a query string ?q=.... should be used? Is there any best practice to follow for this?

Comment: There's no difference between the GET parameters in your example and what you call a "query string". You can concatenate multiple parameters like `/employees?location=london&dateFrom=2020-01-01&dateTo=2020-05-01&gender=male&workLocation=Birmingham`

Comment: Thanks @bkis. I am following API design first with SwaggerHub so maybe that is where the specificity of my request came in where (exactly as you say) I have APIs with multiple query params that can be chained together. A had reviewed the "top dev portals": stripe, paypal etc... and all use "Query parameters" - Source: https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/pubapis_apilist.html !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any best practice to follow for this?

Anything that is consistent with the other identifiers in your API is fine.

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the production rules defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

A query part that is an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation of key value pairs is a popular choice because HTML form support means those resource identifiers are easy to test with a web browser.

`?q=` is just another key value pair -- your values can be pretty much anything so long as they are encoded correctly.  For prior art, see the text area input control in html.

Key value pairs are a way to encode information into the query part, but you aren't required to do that.  `http://example.org/?select%20%2A%20from%20students%3b` is a perfectly satisfactory resource identifier from a REST client perspective.

(Of course, you probably wouldn't want to take an [unsanitized input](https://xkcd.com/327/) and run it in your production relational database using a role authorized to do arbitrary things.)

You aren't restricted to encoding useful information in the query part; if you prefer to encode information into the path segments, that's OK too.  HTML doesn't support that out of the box, but a generalization of the HTML form is a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), which gives you more options for communicating to the client how the URI is to be constructed.